# JSON Data response incorrect position

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a function to call API from the server like this:

```
 getDataSet(callback) {
            request.open('POST', `${apiPath}`);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
                    return callback(null, JSON.parse(request.responseText));
                }
            };
            request.send();
        }

 dataSetDetail.getDataSet((err, response) => {
        if (err) return (console.log(err));
        if (response.success) {
            let data = response.data.dataSetDetails.slice(0, 10);
        }
    });
```

and here is server side:

```
router.post('/:projectid/data/:id', isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
    let dataSetId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    dataSet.getDataSet(dataSetId)
        .then(dataSet => {
            if (!lodash.isNull(dataSet)) {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                return res.json({
                    data: dataSet,
                    success: true,
                });

            } else {
                logger.error('Cannot find data set with id: ' + dataSetId);
                res.redirect('../data');
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            logger.error(e);
            res.redirect('../data');
        })

});
```

The response from the server is:

```
[
  {
    "left": "2",
    "right": "3",
    "operator": "+"
  },
  {
    "left": "6",
     "right": "4"
    "operator": "-"
  }
]
```

but in the client side I received the result sometimes like server side, sometimes like below :

```
[
      {
        "operator": "+",
        "right": "3",
        "left": "2",

      },
      {
        "operator": "-",
        "right": "4",
        "left": "6"
      }
    ]
```

Because I need to display the correct data position on UI. Please give me advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options for you:

#### 1. Use an array

JSON object notation *has no order*. From http://json.org:

> An *object* is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.

*(My emphasis.)*

Although JavaScript objects have an order now (as of ES2015), using it is usually not best practice.

If you need order, and particularly if you need to preserve order through JSON, use an array:

```
[
    ["2", "3", "+"],
    ["6", "4", "-"]
]
```

If you need the property names, send them too:

```
{
    names: ["left", "right", "operator"],
    data:  [
        ["2", "3", "+"],
        ["6", "4", "-"]
    ]
}
```

I **strongly** recommend this over Option 2.

#### 2. Ensure you create `dataSet` in the correct order

If you're dead set on using an object and relying on property order (**not** recommended), and you're using JavaScript at both ends (as you seem to be), *and* your properties on `dataSet` are "own" properties (not inherited) *and* they don't have [integer index names](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type) (your example ones don't), then:

Ensure you create the objects in `dataSet` in the order you want the properties serialized, e.g.:

```
const dataSet = [];
dataSet.push({
    left: "2",
    right: "3",
    operator: "+"
});
```

or

```
const dataSet = [];
let entry = {};
entry.left = "2";
entry.right = "3";
entry.operator = "+";
dataSet.push(entry);
// ...
```

**Not**

```
const dataSet = [];
let entry = {};
entry.operator = "+";  // *** These are
entry.right = "3";     // *** in the
entry.left = "2";      // *** wrong order
dataSet.push(entry);
// ...
```

Don't use `for-in` or `Object.keys`, they aren't specified to follow property order. If you need an array of property names in order, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

The properties will be in the order you want, `JSON.stringify` is specified to follow that order, and `JSON.parse` is specified to create objects with them in that order in the result. So even though JSON doesn't guarantee order, JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` do in very limited contexts.

**Again**, though: **Not** recommended.

> but in the client side I received the result sometimes like server side, sometimes like below

It's more likely that what the server sends varies (perhaps based on branches in the code), and it happens you just looked at one with the order you want. If the server sends the JSON you've shown, `JSON.parse` will preserve that order (see above for why).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the ordering of the JSON attributes will not matter if you are calling the values using (.) dot operators. But you can customize the arrangement using the stringify function. Refer to the code

```js
var output=[
      {
        "operator": "+",
        "right": "3",
        "left": "2",

      },
      {
        "operator": "-",
        "right": "4",
        "left": "6"
      }
    ];

var custom = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( output, ["left","right","operator"] , 4));
console.log(custom);
```

Comment: Thanks, because the content of JSON is dynamic, so I cannot sort by key.

Comment: That's why you can customize it using the stringify, is your problem now solved? or are you facing any other issues?

Comment: That's interesting, though. And as far as I can tell, in-spec, since `JSON.stringify` uses the order given ([indirectly](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-serializejsonobject)), and [`JSON.parse`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-json.parse) uses the order given (because it parses JSON as though it were JavaScript source text, and the order of an object initializer is significant in JavaScript). So although JSON objets are unordered, `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` (if you pass in an array of property names) will preserve the order. Cool! Though I can't think of a good use case... ;-)

Comment: I try to work arround by using that :  let result = [];
            for(let o of output){
                result.push(Object.keys(o).reduceRight((r, k) => (r[k] = o[k], r), {}));
            }. But I'm not sure it run success 100%

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo - `Object.keys` isn't specified to follow object property order. If you want an array of property names that is specified to follow object property order (again: **not** recommended), use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (and weed out the non-enumerable ones, if any; by default, an object has no own, non-enumerable properties).